# Azure Active Directory API Get List

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there's an API to get all Tenant or Active Directory under your account?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Tenants - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) to get the tenants for your account. It's easy to click the green "Try it". Then you will get all the tenants ID for your account.

[image]

Comment: Yup I also did that already but the "Try It" button returns all the tenantId, Im wondering where did that bearer token generated. I can generate a token ID using
https://login.microsoftonline.com/comon/oauth2/token but the parameter is a tenantId. And when I get the token and pass it to that API you said it only return 1 Tenant.

Comment: You could read the [OAuth 2.0 authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)

Comment: That api still need a TenantID parameter.

Comment: You can use one of the tenant to generate the token.

Comment: yes but it will only return 1 tenant and not all tenants.